# How to import numpy in Chaquopy python in android

Tags: python, android, numpy, chaquopy

I am using the `chaquopy` demo for running python in android.
(Taken from GitHub https://github.com/ericdecanini/HelloChaquopy)

My test1 function returns `string`.

When I added the `import numpy as np` line the application stopped running.

In the logcat i get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ericdecanini.chaquopytesttwo/com.ericdecanini.chaquopytesttwo.MainActivity}: com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

```py
import numpy as np
import time
import math

def test1():
    x = math.sin(3.14159/2.0)
    str1 = "%.2f" % x
    str2 = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.gmtime())

    return " --- OK --" + str1 + "\n --- " +str2 + "\n --- "
```

Note: when I commented out the import to numpy it run OK.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding package name as mentioned here in [requirements](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#requirements) section in app build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    python {
        pip {
            install "numpy"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution to import numpy in chaquopy android studio.
Watch this video this will helps you to install any library with chaquopy android studio

https://youtu.be/BDmB3EFy0Qg